# Formfield displayed based on treatment group

Tags: python, html, django, form-fields

I am programming an experiment with different treatment Groups. For Treatment Group 3 and 4, I want to know the name of the Participants by using a form field. For the Control Group and Treatment Group 1 - 2, the name is irrelevant and thus, there should not be a forms_field.

I ws already thinking of excluding the form field in HTML by using if loops, so if treatment = 3 or 4, display the field. However, I cannot proceed to the next page for the other Treatment Groups since the field shouldn't be blank. Inserting a blank=True is not really an option since Treatment Group 3 and 4 could just skip the name. I want to "force" Treatment Group 3 and 4 to give me their name.

My code is too long to post it here, so I'll just post the relevant passages:
Modelsview

```
class Subsession(BaseSubsession):

    def creating_session(self):
        treatmentgroup = itertools.cycle(['ControlGroup','one','two','three', 'four'])
        for p in self.get_players():
            p.treatmentgroup = next(treatmentgroup)

class Group(BaseGroup):
    pass

class Player(BasePlayer):
    name = models.StringField(label="Your Name:")
    transcribed_text = models.LongStringField()
    levenshtein_distance = models.IntegerField()
    guthaben = models.CurrencyField(initial=c(0))
    cumulative_guthaben = models.CurrencyField()
```

Pagesview

```
class Welcome(Page):
    form_model = 'player'

    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.round_number == 1

class Introduction(Page):
    form_model = 'player'

    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.round_number == 1

class Math(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['name']

    def is_displayed(self):
        return self.round_number == 1

    def before_next_page(self):
        if self.round_number == 1:
            self.player.guthaben = self.player.guthaben + Constants.endowment

    def vars_for_template(self):
        return {
            'treatmentgroup': self.player.treatmentgroup,
            'image_path': 'trophy/{}.png'.format(self.round_number)
        }
```

HTML-Page

```
{% extends "global/Page.html" %}
{% load otree static %}

{% block title %}
    The math task
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<p align="justify"> In case you have any questions, please open the door and wait for the experimenter to come to your cubicle.
</p>

{% if treatmentgroup == 'four' or treatmentgroup == 'three' %}

{% formfields %}

{% endif %}



    {% next_button %}



{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a django.forms subclass by using its **init** method. Your code doesn't show how the form gets instantiated, but somewhere you would have

```
form = Form_class() # unbound and

form = Form_class( request.POST ) # bound
```

You would modify these to pass `hide_name=True` if you do not want the name field displayed.

The form itself would include the method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.hide_name = kwargs.pop('hide_name', False)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

self.hide_name is accessible in any method of the form, and form.hide_name in a template that is rendering it. To avoid validation errors you can remove that that field from the form

```
    ...
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.hide_name:
        self.fields.pop('name')
```